# How to set random value into random input tag with javascript

Tags: javascript

Assume I have 25 inputs into a container like below and I want to set value for 5 random input value equal to 5 and the other input have a value equal to 1. How can I do this??? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```js
//create button
var container_content = document.querySelector(".container-content");
for(i=0;i<25;i++){
    var btn = document.createElement("input");
    btn.type ="button";
    container_content.appendChild(btn);
}
//set class and value into container
var btnAll = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(j=0;j<btnAll.length;j++){
    btnAll[j].setAttribute("class","button");
    //i was really confusing in this case
    btnAll[j].setAttribute("value",1)
}
```

```css
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.container{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.container-content{
    width: 258px;
    height: 258px;
    margin:auto;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.container input{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create random index with Math.random() and change input value with this index to 5 (Sorry for my English I'm bad in it)

```
const count = 5;
const neededValue = 5;
//create button
var container_content = document.querySelector(".container-content");
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.type = "button";
  container_content.appendChild(btn);
}
//set class and value into container
var btnAll = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (j = 0; j < btnAll.length; j++) {
    btnAll[j].setAttribute("class", "button");
    //i was really confusing in this case
    btnAll[j].setAttribute("value", 1)
}
for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * btnAll.length);
  btnAll[randomIndex].setAttribute("value", neededValue)
}
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/y0p86tau/7/)

Comment: Np :) Good luck